# GD Text to Image producing weird output

Tags: php, image, gd

I have some GD/PHP code that is trying to create an image out of a string (held in a PHP variable). The output is weird though..

Here is the code: (It looks like there is heaps of whitespace at the start but that is because I indented to insert it here, I still dont understand how to properly use the code insert function of Stackoverflow :/ In my actual code there is no such excessive whitespace.

```
<?php 
        session_start(); 

        //If user is not logged in
        if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            //They aren't meant to be able to access this page. GET THEM OUT OF HERE!
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">top.location=\"index.php\";</script>";
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('You need to be logged in to access this page.');</script>";
        }   else
            {

                //Localise.
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                //Include important settings and functions.
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/config.php');

                //Connect to MySQL Database.
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/connect.php');

                //Let's get the users id.
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($result))
                {
                    $userarray = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());  
                    $userid = $userarray['id'];
                }
            }

        if(!$_GET['i'] || $_GET['id'] != '95dd76e1099af307a37804ecb4d820bd' || $_GET['arid'] != 'b691362f280e16e9a5136d1623ac8156')
        {
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('There was an error with your request.');</script>";
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">top.location=\"members.php\";</script>";
        }   else
            {
                //Decode and localise.
                $articletitle = urldecode($_GET['i']);  
            }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>5StarWriters</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/scrollToTop.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body id="top">

    <!--header -->
    <div id="header-wrap"><header>

            <hgroup>
            <h1><a href="index.html">5StarWriters</a></h1>
            <h3>Quality content, fast.</h3>
        </hgroup>

            <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/navlogged.php'); ?>

            <!-- Login bar can go here -->

    <!--/header--> </header></div>

    <!-- content-wrap -->
    <div id="content-wrap">

        <!-- content -->
        <div id="content" class="clearfix">

            <!-- main -->
            <div id="main">
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `articles` WHERE `title` = '$articletitle'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                    $array = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
                    $articleid = $array['id'];

                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `pendingreview` WHERE `requestid` = '$userid' AND `articleid` = '$articleid'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                    //unset($array); //Clear variable data.
                    $array = mysql_fetch_array($result2); //Lets reload it with some more useful data.

                    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pendingreview` WHERE `requestid` = '$userid' AND ";
                    //$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                ?>
                <center><h1>Pending Review<h1></center>
                <br />
                <center>

    <?php
    $text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

    $arrText=explode("\n",wordwrap($text,75,"\n"));//change number 75 here to check the wordwrap

    $im = @imagecreate(700,500); //creates an image (width,height)
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //sets image background color
    $y=5; //vertical position of text
    foreach($arrText as $arr)
    {
      $white=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255); //sets text color
      imagestring($im,5,15,$y,trim($arr),$white); //create the text string for image,added trim() to remove unwanted chars
      $y=$y+15;

    }
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>

                </center>
                <br /><br /><center>
                </center>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <!-- /main -->
            </div>

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar">

                <div class="about-me">
                        <!-- SIDEBAR CONTENT HERE -->
                </div>

                <div class="sidemenu">

                    <!-- Extra sidebar content -->
                </div>

            <!-- /sidebar -->
            </div>

        <!-- content -->
        </div>

    <!-- /content-out -->
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the output:

> �PNG  IHDR����PLTE���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������= IDATx��X ��44�,�BB @�����'��K]G��53/Qa�-�Q]]��;MÆ 6lذaÆ 6lذaÆ 6�S�/�����)��,����z�z_�Ό��H�<�3�rc��w!|=�m�>n���n�x��As�9�uxֈ�M?�����R&ރ�,-o�}}��3��˚�8Ͼu��M�e���+�9���'�R����&��/0j-�����L _3�zW�QN�;�f#��t�x����D$Ž�<�(�#�<�C�yL�_p���L�6y�X��X�G�qC ��}��&��ej��(#ː�j��H�5[�� �xX�vT,1�m"�e��5���c%ak��ra4�)��z�[f�#^#xE�'�7�;��W)V����� ӡޛ�!�=U�SN���[�� �1ċW�m��7��c�o��&�N�i7-�T��'���Q�tz�x+�R�)�/�H�ݙ߼��a�W��u�[�"LID��[��ͨ0%�N|��@f�`J:�v�P���N�E�&��/��E��"��v4*8�[���4��4�5Q�g����ב+��`$J9䢺�C�-4h��Y�|ыGI�/���R'�a7(�%R ��l�:�v�]y$I���w�1 �Iۮy�Ǿ/�͞iW|o�.�x,`��y��6lذa�>u{�bc�G;��6<�(�����Wխ��N�M���cWⓚX���~�x[�:Ļ�q�xW��hkuM�FX��K�k ���/�5vC�^?��? �˚�8Ͼ��DU��E)F����n���������3 �G��JةlPQ�z[�9",w�B�Qu���|�4�%Բr:{��*�����T���l����9'>p���MT�$S�5��K6Vj��r�����X�����\ˎLJ�x���a%6+M�V��(�Qsj�Db�����!$��]a f�,�m���9N���������ר�&�� f o��x>T�aE�����K'nǔ�ɦ��2v1�5��"N"<ŋ��i�1��*b�9�F�\Hx��u�V"��E�j��Y����d�F�o(I滦��� �s���"�(ن��Ju� ��j h`?y��^�k�~�"�ݮ��ؾ�"�H Ah�k���1y]�@]Qu�x��7_�ӹ�=

There is more of that output, it would just be too long to post.

I have no idea what's going on :/
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just ran your code .. getting perfect output ....try turning on error reporting on your side...

Comment: Where abouts did you run it?

Comment: you've probably got output ocurring somewhere in/before your code, causing the `header()` call to fail and not send the image/png mime-type

Comment: I've removed all headers before and after the code and still the same :/ I've edited in my whole page of code.

Comment: @KriiV I ran it on my localsystem.

Comment: @new_developer I've edited in the full page of code. Can you see any issues? Have I missed a GD library include thats now necessary or something? Maybe it has something to do with ASCII encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy-pasted your code correctly then you have leading white-space in your code:

```
            <?php
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remove it; otherwise the whitespace becomes part of PNG output and therefore results in a "corrupted" image.

## Edit

Now that you have posted your full code: You are mixing PHP code with image's binary data; it does not work that way. Move the code which generates image in a separate file e.g. `article-image.php` then add an image tag in your main HTML which points to that file, e.g.:

```
<img src="article-image.php?id=1">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The text that actually gets converted into the image comes from a database. How would i go about passing that to the image generation code in a secure manner?

Comment: Pass the record id to the image generator script; query the database to grab the text for the corresponding id.

Comment: Thank you! The problem I'm having now is that the image shows but it is just black. There is no text..

Comment: Hard to guess. Your code worked fine with hardcoded text so something must be wrong when you try to fetch the text from db. Comment out gd libary and header functions and check if you can grab the text from db in the first place. If you continue to have problems, ask for help in [PHP chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26543/discussion-between-salman-a-and-kriiv)